# how to use tune_nested() of mlr3tuning?

Tags: mlr3

```
rm(list = ls())
library(mlr3verse)
task <- tsk("pima")
learner <- lrn("classif.rpart")
measure <- msr("classif.ce")
inner_resample <- rsmp("cv", folds = 5)
outer_resample <- rsmp("cv", folds = 5)
search_space <- ps(
  cp = p_dbl(lower = 0.001, upper = 0.1)
)
rr <- tune_nested(
  method = "grid_search",
  resolution = 5,
  task = task,
  learner = learner,
  inner_resampling = inner_resample,
  outer_resampling = outer_resample,
  search_space = search_space,
  term_evals = 5
)
```

i always get this error:

```
Error in terminator_selection(term_evals, term_time) : 
  Assertion on 'term_evals' failed: Must be of type 'single integerish value' (or 'NULL'), not 'ParamSet/R6'.
```

i don't know what's wrong with my code. Someone can give some suggestions?
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3):

You found a bug. We will fix this. However, if you set the `measure`, it should work.

```r
library(mlr3verse)
task <- tsk("pima")
learner <- lrn("classif.rpart")
measure <- msr("classif.ce")
inner_resample <- rsmp("cv", folds = 5)
outer_resample <- rsmp("cv", folds = 5)
search_space <- ps(
  cp = p_dbl(lower = 0.001, upper = 0.1)
)
rr <- tune_nested(
  method = "grid_search",
  resolution = 5,
  task = task,
  learner = learner,
  inner_resampling = inner_resample,
  outer_resampling = outer_resample,
  measure = measure,
  search_space = search_space,
  term_evals = 5
)
```

Comment: oh my god, it confused me for a few days. Hope you can fix it soon.

Comment: I also have another question about `tune` and `tune_nested`, how can i use two measures(more than one measures) in these two functions? Thank you for your answer.

Comment: Do you want to optimize on two measures (multi-criteria optimization) or just optimize on one measure (single-criteria) and additionally score the hyperparameter configurations on a second measure? In the latter case, the tuner ignores the second measure but you can see the performance scores in archive.

Comment: The bug is fixed in the GitHub version. The CRAN version should be online in a few hours. Thanks for reporting.